# Changing blob containers access policy on azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I recently changed azure access policy of the blob containers I'm using in an application, from Public to Private in order to secure them. 
I noticed that some blobs are still accessible without providing a SAS query however they belong to a private container. (https://mydomain.blob.core.windows.net/container/folder/file.extension)
And some other ones are only accessible with generated SAS queries.
Am I missing a step?

Comment: Please check the cache-control property of the blob. It is quite possible that the browser is caching them. When you observe the network traffic, the status code of fetching the blob request should be 304.

Comment: @GauravMantri indeed it was the browser that is caching them. Thanks

Comment: Cool! Let me include this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the browser has cached the blob. Normally if the browser has cached a URL, then the request is not sent to the server and is served directly from the browser itself. To check if the browser has cached the blob, please try to access the blob and observe the network traffic. You should see `304` status code for that request.

Comment: thanks again @Gaurav, however I have a little question. The secured blobs load slower than the unsecured ones, this is a normal behaviour since azure is treating the sas query before returning the requested blob, isn't it?

Comment: I have not seen this behavior. Would you mind sharing more details? I would recommend asking a separate question with all the details on your observations.